# Story or novel with free power generation

Tags: story-identification

Many years ago, maybe in the 80's, I read a story or novel about a future Earth that had been socio-economically devastated by the invention of cheap or free power. The plans for said generator were never sold, but released to the general public and could be built with common items. Hence all the energy companies were immediately superfluous. I don't remember the title, or the author, but I would really like to read that story again. Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Did the release happen during the story?  Or prior to it?  What was the plot?  Any other details that you can remember?

Comment: @Brythan, it was so long ago, I don't remember clearly. It may have been an anthology. The first chapter explained the invention of the generator, so I assume all of the story/stories were post-invention.

Comment: Did the people who developed it put the plans on the net with a lot of superfluous machinery and let someone else get credit for "simplifying" it back to the original state of construction?

Answer (score 10):

From the part of the description about the public release of the discovery, could be Heinlein's "[Let There Be Light](https://archive.org/stream/Super_Science_Stories_v01n02_1940-05#page/n35/mode/2up)" (link to online version at archive.org).

Summary from Wikipedia:

> The story concerns the invention of "light panels" - devices which turn electrical power directly into light (similar to electroluminescent displays, invented in 1949[1](https://archive.org/stream/Super_Science_Stories_v01n02_1940-05#page/n35/mode/2up)). In the course of their discovery, the inventors also discover that these panels can also be used to derive power from light. In attempting to bring their discovery to market, they encounter the active opposition of the Power Syndicate, a conglomeration of energy-producing companies dedicated to preserving their monopoly on power production. Rather than trying to maintain a patent on their invention, the scientists then publicly release the scientific details of their discovery for a small royalty, allowing anyone to obtain their own power, and thus outwitting the Power Syndicate.

Comment: I don't believe that is the story, the units were more like miniaturized cold fusion reactors,. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I can think of at least two free power stories -

Jack Williamson's [The Equalizer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45666) tells how the invention of a device that provides free energy brought down the dictatorial government. It's told from the viewpoint of returning space travelers who were gone during the transition.

Theodore Sturgeon's [Brownshoes](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45046) is about the inventor of a free power device who has to struggle against entrenched interests to get his device out to the world. This ends on more of a utopian note.

Answer (score 7):

I'm wondering if you are thinking of the Bending Converter, from the fiction of Randall Garrett.  If so, I have good news for you: you can find the stories on Project Gutenberg.

I'm aware of two references to the Bending Converter.

First was the story about its invention, published in 1960: "Damned If You Don't"  https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/24064

> "It's powered by deuterium?"
>
> Bending delivered his bombshell. "Nope. Water. Plain, ordinary aitch-two-oh. See those little vents at the side? They exhaust oxygen and helium. It burns about four hundred milligrams of water per hour at maximum capacity."
>
> Olcott had either regained control of himself or had passed the saturation point; Sam couldn't tell which. Olcott said: "Where do you put the water?"
>
> "Why put water in it?" Sam asked coolly. "That small whirring sound you hear isn't the hydrogen-helium conversion; it's a fan blowing air through a cooling coil. Even in the Sahara Desert there's enough moisture in the air to run this baby."
>
> "And the fan is powered—"
>
> "... By the machine itself, naturally," said Bending. "It's a self-contained unit.

The last third of the story is an extended discussion of what would happen if the invention became widely available: another Great Depression.  Spoiler, the invention does leak out.

The second mention is in the novel *Unwise Child*, set in approximately the year 2090.  Part of the backstory of that novel is that there was a Depression caused by the Bending Converter.  https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/23335

> At the end of the last century, the Bending Converter had almost wrecked the economy of the entire world, since it gave to the world a source of free energy. Sam Bending’s “little black box” converted ordinary water into helium and oxygen and energy—plenty of energy. A Bending Converter could be built relatively cheaply and for small-power uses—such as powering a ship or automobile or manufacturing plant—could literally run on air, since the moisture content of ordinary air was enough to power the converter itself with plenty of power left over.
>
> Overnight, all previous forms of power generation had become obsolete. Who would buy electric power when he could generate his own for next to nothing? Billions upon billions of dollars worth of generating equipment were rendered valueless. The great hydroelectric dams, the hundreds of steam turbines, the heavy-metal atomic reactors—all useless for power purposes. The value of the stock in those companies dropped to zero and stayed there. The value of copper metal fell like a bomb, with almost equally devastating results—for there was no longer any need for the millions of miles of copper cable that linked the power plants with the consumer.
>
> The Depression of 1929-42 couldn’t even begin to compare with The Great Depression of 1986-2000. Every civilized nation on Earth had been hit and hit hard. The resulting governmental collapses would have made the disaster even more complete had not the then Secretary General of the UN, Perrot of Monaco, grabbed the reins of government. Like the Americans Franklin Roosevelt and Abraham Lincoln, he had forced through unconstitutional bills and taken extra-constitutional powers. And, like those Americans, he had not done it for personal gain, but to preserve the society. He had not succeeded in preserving the old society, of course, but he had built, almost single-handedly, a world government—a new society on the foundations of the old.

I don't know if this is what you are thinking of.  *Unwise Child* is actually more about artificial intelligence; the power generation thing is pure backstory.

By the way, in the short story, hydrogen fusion power plants are described as commonplace and the delightful word "stellarator" is apparently the common word to describe them.

Comment: "stellarator" is a thing in the real world. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendelstein_7-X

Comment: That sounds like the work/device sought by the OP for sure. Hopefully they will return to confirm it.

Comment: I've been looking at the deleted answer and the comments surprised me. I didn't realise that there are now AI generated answers to some of the questions in here.